# Processing.js mouse issue

Tags: html, processing, processing.js

I am trying to load a "fractalizing" sketch I made (it can build a 2d fractal from the first linear shape the mouse gives). It works fine when I compile it from my computer (from the terminal) but when I load it in a html page, the left mouse just turns the screen blank instead of starting the render of the fractal. Is there a problem with mouse inputs with processingJS? The canvas where this is loaded on the hmtl page should work the same as if run from the terminal. Here is a link to the github code [KochFractal](https://github.com/AndrewKaiser/Processingjs-example). and here is the [webpage](http://andrewkaiser.github.io/Processingjs-example/)

Comment: The web console reports `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function andrewkaiser.github.io/:88` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of null andrewkaiser.github.io/:166`

Comment: In addition, you probably want to use `noLoop()` in the setup, and then use Processing's `redraw()` at the end of event handlers (like `mouseClicked`) instead of redrawing unchanging content at maximum framerate. Also note that Processing has no visbility model. There is no `public`/`private`/`protected` system (those are Java subsyntax and only do anything when a Processing sketch runs on a JVM)